# How to get hex code of the gradient color (3 colors based on values) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, colors, gradient

I'm trying to get hex code with in the 3 mixed colors based on values.

### Example:

1. Start - `#FF0000` (Red).
2. Middle - `#FFFF00` (Yellow).
3. End - `#008000` (Green).

If the value is:

1 - hex code is `#FF0000`

50 - hex code is `#FFFF00`

100 - hex code is `#008000`

In between values like, **1-50** the hex code should mixed with *Red-Yellow*.

**50-100** hex code mixed with *Yellow-Green* based on value increasing.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Tried like what in the link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143082/how-to-get-color-value-from-gradient-by-percentage-with-javascript   but not find anything

Comment: Then please show your attempt at using the function there and explain how it failed for you, because currently from your description, the answer there is a correct answer to your question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```js
function change(e) { 
  box.style.background = gradient(e.target.value/100,'#FF0000','#FFFF00','#008000'); 
}

// t in ragne 0..1, start-middle-end are colors in hex e.g. #FF00FF
function gradient(t,start,middle,end) {  
  return t>=0.5 ? linear(middle,end,(t-.5)*2) : linear(start,middle,t*2);
}

function linear(s,e,x) {
  let r = byteLinear(s[1]+s[2], e[1]+e[2], x);
  let g = byteLinear(s[3]+s[4], e[3]+e[4], x);
  let b = byteLinear(s[5]+s[6], e[5]+e[6], x);
  return "#" + r + g + b;
}

// a,b are hex values from 00 to FF; x is real number in range 0..1
function byteLinear(a,b,x) {
  let y = (('0x'+a)*(1-x) + ('0x'+b)*x)|0;
  return y.toString(16).padStart(2,'0') // hex output
}
```

```css
#box { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #FF0000 }
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" oninput="change(event)" value="0">
<div id="box"></div>
```