# How to search an item across many arrays efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 arrays and I need to find the array where the string matches.

Eg:

```js
var arr1 = ['apple','banana','orange'];
var arr2 = ['abc','def','ghi'];
var arr3 = ['james','joe','robert','msg'];
var search = "abc joe 12345 msg:(somecontent)";
var arr = search.split(' ');
        
    for(var i in arr){
        
        if(arr1.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) {
          console.log('Found in arr1');
        }
        else if(arr2.indexOf(arr[i])!= -1){
          console.log('Found in arr2');
        }
        else if(arr3.indexOf(arr[i])!=-1){
          console.log('Found in arr3');
        }
        else{
          console.log('Not Found');
        }
        
    }
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this search when there are thousands of items in each array.

One more trouble I had with the search string is that, I need msg to be split out from the (somecontent). One thing I can do is to split that `arr[3].split(":");`. But the problem is msg:(somecontent) does not appear at the same position every time. So I cannot do the `arr[3].split(":");`. I'm searching only in 'arr'. If I do the `arr[3].split(":");`, I will create a new array and I won't be searching in that. I don't think I can avoid the second array.

Comment: how will the string match will array?

Comment: if you can change the order of array use [binary search algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697936/binary-search-in-javascript)

Comment: Why do you need this to be efficient? Is there an actual performance reason or is this just premature optimization?

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız Binary search on string array?

Comment: @Soviut That's what I think. I need to tokenize such strings, around 40k of them, and append them to html table.

Comment: There is no efficient way to search a totally random array, if it's sorted or have some other characteristics then that's another story. Otherwise, there is no other way other than looking at each element one by one.

Comment: @SaiVelamuri yes if you can sort the array straight you can check it in js

Comment: Concerning the `split(":")` trouble. Use regular expression in split:  `var arr = search.split(/ |:/);`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3pmmxhhz/)

Answer (score 0):

If you think there could be too many iterations of this code (for which you need optimization), you might afford some effort on sorting and combining the data into a single array of unique values. Then use binary search.

Comment: You should improve your answer by explaining what a binary search is and give examples and links.

Comment: If he found the index in 'unique array' then how he know what is the real index and real array ? Think there is same string in 2 different array. And there will 1 of that string in 'unique array'. It will not work

Comment: @Burak, The current code that he has shared does not show the index anyway. Hence his requirement will be met.

Comment: @vikas It is not an answer for that question too 'find the array where the string matches'

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string using regex

```
var a = ['amy', 'john', 'dev', 'garret', 'frank', 'sean', 'happy'];
var str = 'Amy test dev msg:(car runs slowly) happy   ...';
sort(a);
// Array a will look like below
// ["amy", "dev", "frank", "garret", "happy", "john", "sean"]
```

Strings are sortable so you can split your array in the middle. If string in part A then keep splitting part A otherwise part B. This will quick get you the result.

```
function search( arr, str ) {
    while ( arr.length > 1 ) {
        var m = Math.floor( arr.length / 2 );
        if ( str >= arr[m] ) {
            arr.splice( 0, m );
        } else {
            arr.splice( m );
        }
  }

  if ( arr[0] == str ) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple, but at the same time most useful optimization is to use objects for `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`. This way you can use `arr1[word]` (or `obj1` will be more appropriate naming now) instead of `arr1.indexOf(word)`. In general former complexity will be `O(1)` (as this is a hash table) and later - `O(n)`.