# Substring Binary search in array with duplicates in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary-search

I have an array (1000 pieces) of brands, where I would like to provide a fast search. So when I start typing ie: "m" then I should get "mammut" and "millet". The array is sorted. So does anybody know a fast solution which doesn't need to loop through the whole array? Best in javascript. Thanks

```
var brands = new Array("arcterix", "mammut", "millet", "ortovox", ... )

function search(brands, substring){
 // will return array of founded brands which begins on substring
}
```

Comment: well you have to loop through it once at least.... Than each character you can loop over the subset...

Comment: I think you are a beginner and don't about search engines. You should use ElasicSearch : https://www.elastic.co/ or Solr: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

or if it a basic task than you have loop as suggested by @epascarello

Comment: @epascarello I am not sure if I need to loop it once at least because when I type for exampe "m" than I know I need to search somewhere in middle and use a binary search. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @ArwinEdward somehow you need to know where `m` is.... So yes you can do a search to figure out where the start of "m" is. ou can try it and see if it is faster than just looping.

Comment: 1000 is not a lot... Use loop or `[].reduce`, or `[].filter`.

Comment: @epascarello yes I know but for figuring where m is I have smaller complexity (i think O log n ) than with looping whole array (O n). I am wondering if javascript have some built functions for that, or I need to reinvent wheel once again. 
Aabir Hussain Elastic search is really large, I need just nice small function which can handle this search.

Comment: There is not built in functionality, only way you could make it fast is preprocess the data so it is an an object lookup instead of an array. `var words = { a: ["animal","apple"], b: [], c: [] ....}`

Comment: As noted, you probably don't need anything fancy for your particular use case. That said, if you are interested in implementing a binary search function, see [Binary Search in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697936/binary-search-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var brands = ["arcterix", "mammut", "millet", "ortovox"]

function search(brands, substring){
 return brands.filter( i => i.startsWith(substring) )
}

console.log(search(brands, 'm')) // ['mammut', 'millet']
```

This is very fast. It's almost impossible to do things faster, everything is optimized for you.

Comment: This is indeed the best and the only proper way to do this for just 1000 items :) However, it is far from being the fastest algorithm and it is not "optimized". This algorithm works for `O(n*pLen)` where `pLen` is the length of a prefix. The main point here is that input array is sorted and therefore it can be improved by utilizing binary search.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes, but the question feels to me like the author is quite a newbie. So I've infered that this solution is nothing more than what he needs.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Perfect! :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev and is there a binary search library for js, or I need to implement myself?

Comment: @ArwinEdward You would have to implement it yourself, it is pretty simple algorithm, but its usage case is tricky, because you need find both left-most and right-most occurence, and then do the same recursively for all following letters. **But**...as already mentioned by Nurbol, it simply won't bring any improvement for 1000 items. No need to overengineer it. Binary search would make sense here, if you get closer to millions of items. I just corrected the statement that it is "very fast and it's almost impossible to do things faster" :)