# Binary search in a numerical array

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have a sorted array, the first value is always equal or grater than 1, and I need to find the index of the element most to the left, which is equal or greater than `N`.

```js
[1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 11, 11, 12, 15]
```

What I need is a recursive binary search function that finds the expected element, so in the example, when `N` is equal to `11`, it returns `6` as an output.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: _"What I need is a recursive binary search function that finds the expected element"_ - Have fun implementing it (SO is not a free code writing service). If you have an actual problem with it you can come back and we will help you with that (assuming you provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem).

Comment: @TigranAbrahamyan How does `.indexOf()` help?

Comment: @Andreas ```.indexOf()``` is always return the first finded index

Comment: @TigranAbrahamyan And for `N = 10`?

Comment: `findIndex(v => v >= N)` will do it with a linear search.

Comment: A binary search implementation is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29018745/1563833)

Answer (score 1):

EDITED!!!

Ok, now I got the question asked, my previous response was because of not reading well the question. The answer is not much complex than previous. Note: If there's no value >= n, index will be -1, otherwise you'll get the index of the first met value in your sorted array >= n.

```js
var n = 11;
var idx = [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 11, 11, 12, 15].findIndex(each => each >= n);
console.log('idx = '+idx);
```

Comment: And for `N = 10`?

Comment: now reading the question well , I've posted an edit which is probably the lightest solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop will do the trick, as seen with how it is implemented in this function.

```
let arr=[1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 11, 11, 12, 15]; // Array you want to test
let n=11; // Number to be n
function getVal(a,num){
   for(let i=0;i<a.length;++i){
      if(a[i]>=num)return i; // Look for val that's >= n.
   }
}
getVal(arr,n);
```

Comment: How is that a binary search?  And why are you reimplementing Array.findIndex