# How to match values in arrays efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have two Arrays `a` and `b`. I want to add information which is contained in `b` to array `a`.

`a` and `b` both have a keyNum which I will be using to match the needed information in `b` to the relevant record in `a`.

`a` is formatted like:

```
a = [
  {
    keyNum: 'ABC00001234',
    Date: '20240325 00:00:00.000',
    Cost: '57.95',
    _ItemId: 'c38637b7-f901-4d39-9e29-91910109ffa5'
  },
  {
    keyNum: 'ABC00001234',
    Date: '20240325 00:00:00.000',
    Cost: '102.56',
    _ItemId: '504f2b09-429e-443d-993f-4371eedaee76'
  }
]
```

With elements ordered by `keyNum (with descending ordering).

`b` is formatted like:

```
b = [
  {
    keyNum: 'ABC0001234',
    infoNeededIna: 'x13',
    _ItemId: '51c1666b-96bc-4b75-b001-ef698be8193c'
  },
  {
    keyNum: 'ABC0001233',
    infoNeededIna: 'A30',
    _ItemId: '5f0b331c-94ae-4378-9ecd-8af41f74502d'
  }
]
```

The desired output would be like:

```
a = [
  {
    keyNum: 'ABC00001234',
    Date: '20240325 00:00:00.000',
    Cost: '57.95',
    _ItemId: 'c38637b7-f901-4d39-9e29-91910109ffa5',
    infoNeededIna: 'x13'
  },
  {
    keyNum: 'ABC00001234',
    Date: '20240325 00:00:00.000',
    Cost: '102.56',
    _ItemId: '504f2b09-429e-443d-993f-4371eedaee76',
    infoNeededIna: 'x13'
  }
]
```

With elements also ordered, but not necessarily descending.

The data in the arrays comes as JSON strings which I have called from an API. the keyNum is an order number. B is essentially the parent which contains records of A in the database I am grabbing this from. Unfortunately, the info I need in B is not contained in the record of A

I need `infoNeededIna` into the a record where ever `keyNum` is equal between a and b. a and b have a many to one relationship to so it is likely that keeping track of the index i am looking in b would be much more efficient than starting the search at the first record each time.

I know how I could brute force this but I wanted to see if anyone knew a more elegant solution.

My thoughts now is that I could use a loop through a and use the `keyNum` to then pilot an inner loop into b to search for the relevant index of b and grab `infoNeededIna`.

Comment: If would help if you could give some actual examples of what's contained in your arrays (which are NOT JSON, by the way; JSON is a string). What have you tried and why doesn't it meet your expectations?

Comment: Technical note: you don't have "JSON arrays", you have "arrays". Arrays of objects, even. JSON is string data that you can't do anything meaningful with until you convert it to JS, at which point whatever JSON you had becomes irrelevant. With that covered: how are the elements in `a` and `b` are ordered, because that determines whether brute force is all you're going to get, or whether you can do a binary search

Comment: Remember not to provide additional details in a comment, they [go in your post](/help/how-to-ask). But the question was whether a and b are _ordered_ in any way, so not whether they have a property that can be used for ordering but whether that ordering has already been applied. Is every element in both a and b followed by an element with a "higher" keyNum?

Comment: What do you mean with `The data in the arrays are JSON strings`? You're showing JS, not strings. Please either show your real code (in which case show strings), or change your description to match your real code (in which case there is no JSON anywhere). That said: if both `a` and `b`  are sorted, you can iterate over all elements in `a` and get the corresponding elements from `b` by using a [binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697936/binary-search-in-javascript) on `b` based on `keyNum` comparison.

Comment: Your example is very scarce, please provide bigger a & b in the proper order of elements inside

Comment: Apologies as I'm trying to be a bit vague on the contents of the data. I added an essentially real example of both a and b.

Comment: What's the desired output, per your example?

Comment: your items in a have the same keyNum: ABC00001234. seems they should be the same in the output

Answer (score 0):

Just create a map and update a from it:

```js
const a = [
  {
    keyNum: 1,
    extra: 'test'
  }
]

const b = [
  {
    keyNum: 1,
    extra2: 'from B'
  }
];


const map = b.reduce((r, item) => (r[item.keyNum] = item, r), {});
a.forEach(a => Object.assign(a, map[a.keyNum]));

console.log(a);
```

Comment: That's... pretty much the brute forcing they're asking how to avoid =)